# как работает substringAfterLast

Tags: kotlin

Я делаю программу. И мне надо найти символы после определенной строки. Делаю вот так:

```
if (txt.text.toString().substringAfterLast('/')) {
    a = txt.text.toString()
}
```

но что то не работает. Как можно это сделать

Comment: `Возвращает подстроку после последнего вхождения разделителя. Если строка не содержит разделитель, возвращает missingDelimiterValue, которое по умолчанию соответствует исходной строке.`

Answer (score 1):

`substringAfterLast("/")` возвращает `String`, а не `Boolean`.
Если Вам нужно что то конкретное, то делайте сверку. Если просто наличие, то добавьте `.isNotBlank()`